# ModelAndView passed object is null

Tags: spring-mvc

Ok, I'm completely newbie to Spring MVC. There should be an obvious missing part but I'm unable to see it for hours. JSP says my passed data is null.

This is my dispatcher sevlet, nothing too different in sample xml in Netbeans, cut some parts like namespaces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
  <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>
  <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
  <props>
    <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
    <!--<prop key="hello.htm">helloController</prop> -->
  </props>
</property>
</bean>

<bean name="/hello.oi" class="controllers.HelloController"/>

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
    p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
    p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
    p:viewName="index" />
</beans>
```

This is my controller HelloController:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
  @RequestMapping
  public ModelAndView hello() {
    String str = "this is my message";
    System.out.println(str);
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    mav.setView("hello");
    mav.addObject("msg", str);
    return mav;    
  }
}
```

And this is the JSP file hello.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>${msg eq null}...</h1>
  <br />
  <h1>${msg}...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller method prints message to console but JSP renders "true..." and well, nothing instead of my message..

Comment: Your controller code cannot compile. There is no .setView(String) in ModelAndView, only .setView(View) and .setViewName(String). Please check your code and come back with the correct sources.

Answer (score 0):

Using `${msg}` denotes that you're using Spring EL, to do this you'll need to include the spring tag library:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

Without the Spring EL library you have to access a model and view object via the request object eg:

```
request.getAttribute("msg")
```